# Apache equivalent of Nginx `proxy_buffering off`

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have an application that requires me to disable buffering in the reverse proxy. I managed to do that with the following nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  10.0.0.104;

  location / {
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_pass http://http_backend;
    proxy_redirect default;
  }
}

upstream http_backend {
  server 10.0.0.86:8080;

  keepalive 16;
}
```

I need to have the same setup working on Apache but apache doesn't have a `proxy_buffering off` directive. The only conf that I was able to find in the [mod_proxy docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) is `ProxyIOBufferSize` and `ProxyReceiveBufferSize` but they have a minimun value instead of an option to disable buffering. I tested with those but my application fails.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to set proxy_buffering off in Apache?

Comment: @spuder I ended up using HAProxy instead.

Comment: What's the version of your Nginx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**flushpackets=on** means flushing out the buffer after each chunk is sent

This example is from the guacamole docs: https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/proxying-guacamole.html#proxying-with-apache

```
<Location /guacamole/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    ProxyPass http://HOSTNAME:8080/guacamole/ flushpackets=on
    ProxyPassReverse http://HOSTNAME:8080/guacamole/
</Location>
```